# Instance of a C++ vector in python (for TTrees in pyROOT)

Tags: python, c++, boost, cython, root-framework

I am trying to make a filter for a TTree (a ROOT object) in python using `pyROOT`. I have getting information from a TTree with several branches, some of which are C++ type `vector<int>`, `vector<float>` or `vector<string>`'s.

In order to pass information into a new tree, I need to access that from the old tree, I need to pass the address of a vector etc to the tree, which is then populated. To do this I need access to the address of such a new vector. This is quite easy in C++, but after looking at Cython and boost, I am unable to work it out. Ultimately I would like something like:

```
cppintvectorinpython = getcppintvector()    
oldtree.setbranchaddress(branchname,cppintvectorinpython)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

CINT exports a number of STL classes for you, among them `std::vector`. To create e.g. a `std::vector<double>` from pyROOT do

```
import ROOT as r
vec = r.vector('double')()
```

Setting the branch address of the `TTree` is then pretty transparent due to pyROOT, e.g. you don't need to use pointers

```
tree = r.gDirectory.Get('oldtree')
tree.SetBranchAddress("vec_branch_name", vec)
```